Are weak acid reactions reversible?
I know sometimes weak acid reactions are written as  $\ce {HA <=> H+ + A-}$.
However the $\ce{<=>}$ sign here confuses me. I'm not sure if all weak acid reactions are reversible. I imagine some could be and some couldn't be but I can't see them all being so.
The main reason I'm questioning this is because here they claim that because these reactions don't go $100\%$ to completion 'it is more appropriate to write it as a reversible reaction' rather than because the reactions are actually reversible themselves. This substantiates my argument even though these $\ce{<=>}$ signs are used everywhere for this type of reaction.

In principle, all reactions are reversible. But this sign says there's equilibrium - proton exchange is extremally fast and you get a local eq. instantly.

An acid (by some definitions) has to dissociate into protons. A strong acid is one which produces protons in solution AND whose conjugate base is (also by definition) not strong enough to cause any meaningful reformation of the original species—otherwise it wouldn't be a strong acid. A weak acid therefore, is one which does dissociate into protons, but whose conjugate base is strong enough to reform the original protonated molecule to some degree. That makes the dissociation and protonation reactions reversible and in equilibrium with each other.

Any time you see an equilibrium constant less than infinity, the reaction is reversible.


[OP] However the $\ce{<=>}$
sign here confuses me. I'm not sure if all weak acid reactions are reversible. I imagine some could be and some couldn't be but I can't see them all being so.

The $\ce{<=>}$ implies that the reaction, rather than going to completion, will attain an equilibrium where all species (reactants and products) are present at constant concentration, and where the rate of the forward and reverse reaction is nonzero (and equal - otherwise the concentration would change).

[OP] The main reason I'm questioning this is because here they claim that because these reactions don't go 100% to completion 'it is more appropriate to write it as a reversible reaction' rather than because the reactions are actually reversible themselves.

You could imagine a reaction not going to completion because some molecules react and others just don't. Once the "willing" molecules reacted, the reaction is done, and the "lazy" reactant molecules remain. However, this would imply that two molecules (or species) that are identical behave in non-identical ways. You could imagine purifying the lazy reactant molecules and trying the reaction again, and it should not make product at all. This is not a model that explains reality.
The other explanation is compatible with the observations. All molecules of a species behave the same way. There is a certain chance that reactants form products, and a certain chance that products form reactants. This leads to equilibrium constants describing the equilibrium, and to the realization that the reaction does not stop, but that you get to a point where forward and reverse reactions happen at equal rate.

[OP] Are weak acid reactions reversible?

Yes, they all are. You can show that by isolating the conjugate base, $\ce{A-}$ or  e.g. $\ce{KA}$ and demonstrating that it is able to turn into $\ce{AH}$ again when in water.
$$\ce{KA + H2O <=> K+ + HA + OH-}$$

When dissolving any weak acid $\ce{HA}$ in water, a fraction of its molecules are dissociated according to $$\ce{HA -> H+ + A- \tag{1}}$$ This reaction does not go to completion. It stops when $\ce{HA, H+ and A-}$ have numerical values such that the fraction $\ce{ \frac {[H^+][A^-]}{[HA]}}$ is equal to the constant $\pu{K_a}$ of the weak acid.
Adding now some soluble salt like $\ce{NaA}$ into the previous solution produces a supplement of $\ce{A-}$ ions in solution. Due to  mass action, the following reverse reaction occurs which destroys part of the added $\ce{A-}$ ions : $$\ce{H+ + A- -> HA \tag{2}}$$ The reaction ($2$) stops when the new values of $\ce{[H+], [A-] and [HA]}$ give a numerical value of the fraction $\ce{ \frac {[H^+][A^-]}{[HA]}}$ which must be equal to the original value $\pu{K_a}$. A new equilibrium is then established.
This reaction ($2$) is the inverse of ($1$). It shows that the dissociation reaction ($1$) is always at least partially reversible. This is true for all weak acids.
This answers Badusername's question.
